# How to launch bat file on server with PHP (From Website)

Tags: php, file, cmd, exec, launch

I am hosting a website and minecraft server off of my windows computer, with IIS. They both work perfectly except for that I'd like a way to start the minecraft server from the website. I have a batch file I run to start it regularly so I thought perhaps I could launch that batch file. Some things I've tried:

```
exec("cmd.exe /C start server.bat");

shell_exec('start server.bat');
```

I've given  IUSR and IIS_IUSRS all permissions on cmd and on the server folder. If it's easier I could also try just running the code within the batch file, from php too. Here is what's inside the server.bat:

```
cd C:\Users\username\Desktop\_MCServ
:begin
java -Xms3072m -Xmx3072m -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2.xml -jar spigot-1.14.jar
timeout 5
echo resuming server...
goto begin
```

The loop is so if the server stops, it can automatically start itself again.

Comment: ok, that is not good really. you invoke java 5 seconds instead of checking if it is running before attempting to start another instance.

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work you need to run it using cmd and give it an exact path to the bat file. The following code should work for what you need.
`system("cmd /c C:[path to file]");`

Comment: When I do this, the page continues to load forever. Nothing is displayed and nothing opens on my computer.

Comment: have you checked that the .bat file works on its own? if that is good try opening the console in inspect element to see if any errors show up when your code runs